# If I'm typing into a comment, confirming the IME should probably not submit the comment

Tags: support, bug, comments

I was typing a comment into a comment box today. At some point while doing this, I wanted to type a Japanese word into the comment.

So I switch to the Japanese IME with <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd>.
I type some letters and then hit <kbd>space</kbd> a few times to select the right completion. At this point, I am happy with the word it's showing, so I hit <kbd>return</kbd> to accept the word, and for some reason the JavaScript on the page thought I was submitting the comment and stopped editing it.

I'm pretty sure it isn't supposed to do that.

The first time I had hit some other keys and then <kbd>delete</kbd> as well, so I ended up on the previous page and wasn't sure how the focus had even left the text field.

Luckily (?), I was completing a second word in there, which allowed me to figure out what was going on.

In case it matters:

- OSX 10.11.1 (15B42)
- Google Chrome 47.0.2526.106 (64-bit)

Comment: Confirming that it occurs on meta.stackoverflow.com as well as stackoverflow.com.

Comment: what what what what fジウェウォwhq

Comment: .... confirmed. Appears to happen because the `keydown` event is being used to submit the form, rather than `keypress` or the real `submit` event, neither of which are triggered by selecting the word in the popup.

Comment: Related on MSE: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216834/pressing-enter-in-an-input-method-editor-should-not-submit-comments

Comment: What IME do you use?  It may have some options to mitigate the problem.

Comment: As noted in [my answer on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/217499), I've written a [user script](http://stackapps.com/questions/4486/stack-overflow-unofficial-patch) to fix this and a bunch of other interface bugs on SO/SE. While waiting for the devs to fix this for everyone, you might want to give it a try.

Comment: I'm curious why you'd _need_ Japanese characters on SO, though...

Comment: @Cerbrus I can guess it has something to do with a question about unicode :)

Comment: @Gimby: That's possible, but then it's still odd that the user has a Japanese IME available, _and_ it has to be used in comments...

Comment: The same happens if you navigate through the context menu and press enter

Comment: @Cerbrus I've answered at least one Unicode question that hinged on knowledge of Devanagari. Having to use it in a clarification comment before answering or in a followup comment after answering is not one bit outlandish. Seems to me having to use Japanese is just as banal as my case with Devanagari. I was just lucky that my IME for Devanagari does not need confirmations.

Comment: @Cerbrus isn't there a Stack Overflow in Japanese now?

Comment: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/12/stack-overflow-in-japanese/ @mikeTheLiar

Comment: https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/12/stack-overflow-in-japanese/ @Cerbrus

Comment: @Cerbrus I had asked a particular question I had about Kuromoji (a lexical analyser for Japanese) over on SO, where I wanted to comment about how I wondered why two of the tokens/terms happened to come out of the analyser in one situation yet not the other. At the time, I wasn't thinking much about why I was switching inputs, but I guess I just did the usual thing of trying not to involve the mouse, which would have been required to copy and paste the existing example on the screen.

Comment: @Ding-YiChen Kotoeri (the OSX default. I haven't tried Google's for a while, but the last time I tried it, the lack of shift-to-type-katakana was upsetting.)