# Using (specifically Japanese) IME in comments

Tags: support, bug

It has come to my attention that across all sites in the network, when using a Japanese IME (on a PC) whilst writing a comment, pressing the Enter button to select your Kanji from the dropdown menu leads to the [Add Comment] button being triggered.

Whilst I am sure this is intended behaviour (on US-based Keyboards), it makes it difficult to type comments whilst using either an IME or a CJK keyboard.

Is there some way to get around this, or is there some browser setting which needs to be changed in order for the enter button to function for both Kanji selection and Add Comment selection separately?

Comment: @Zaq Ahh that would explain it. I have been frustrated with this for quite a while and only got round to asking about it today. Obviously I haven't commented on the Japanese Language Exchange in a while. It doesn't seem to have been implemented network-wide yet though. I guess I have to wait a little longer.

Comment: On what other site besides Japanese Language would you want to use a Japanese IME for?  Think of  the use cases here; would it make any practical sense to type a Japanese comment anywhere else where others may not understand it?  That is to say, what value is there in making this global?

Comment: @Makoto [スタック・オーバーフロー](http://ja.stackoverflow.com/)? I would assume they have the IME solution enabled there too, however.

Comment: @Laurel:  Yes, Stack Overflow in Japanese would also have it, but again - "global" implies that it's enabled *everywhere*, not just in the places where it needs it.  Could someone point me in the direction of a valid reason as to why we need it *everywhere*?

Comment: @Makoto Most of the time, it's not. But if the question involves Unicode, then it might be. See also: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314068

Comment: Along with the Enter key, ESC should also be paid attention to.

Comment: @Makoto I live and work in Japan and my computer, software and coding is all in Japanese. I extensively use the IME as well as many other Japanese-related functions across all facets of software. You might as well be asking why any language except English is supported across the network. If you have to explain some part of your question in the comments that may contain Japanese, then this is why you would need this behaviour globally. I could list plenty of times across sites that wouldn't seem to use it where it has actually been used.

Comment: I remember a blog entry where he posted the code, maybe a user script can be cooked... that replaces the event.

Comment: There was a network wide implementation according to the blog post. However, I just tried it on a few network sites and most of the time it works, however sometimes it can be patchy and still attempt to post on Kanji confirmation.